# Unresponsive keyboard key even after RMA

Tags: usb, keyboard, hardware-failure, peripherals, unresponsive

I have a Steelseries Apex 350 keyboard on Windows 10. Recently the numpad minus key (-) stopped working unless I first press shift. Here are the steps I've taken to resolve the issue (not ordered):

- Done an RMA w/ Steelseries. The new keyboard has the same problem.
- Tried it on another computer (it works fine).
- Removed the device/drivers in Windows and uninstalled the Steelseries engine software.
- Reinstalled the drivers/software.
- Tried multiple USB 2 and USB 3 ports.
- Tried contacting Steelseries official support.

Steelseries has not been helpful. They keep trying to give me another RMA and another new keyboard.

Comment: Evidently it is not compatible with Windows 10, their support sucks also. I don't want another friggin keyboard, I want this one to work on my version of W10!

Comment: I would hate to be a hardware developer for windows 10, what a nightmare, windows 10 changes with each major update.

Comment: @Moab It's worked fine on this system for months, and I have two other friends with the same keyboard. They aren't experiencing problems either. I assume it has to be something on my system causing the issue, but I've run out of ideas short of pressing the big red button (reformat and start over).

Comment: TBH, I have had a few Steelseries mice and ending throwing both of them in the garbage as the quality of them sucked.  Try a different brand.

Comment: @Keltari I've found that for me there is no single manufacturer that does all peripherals correctly. I love Logitech mice, Razer headsets, and Steelseries Keyboards. I won't judge the quality of their KB based on reports of their mice. Aside from this one issue with this key (and again it's only on my PC), I absolutely love this KB. Better than any I've ever owned.